# SCF calculations using HSE hybrid functional dying/stopping?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I am trying to perform an SCF calculation using HSE hybrid functional to measure the band gap of a 2D semiconductor, but my calculation reached the level of calculating the exact exchange and seemingly stopped. Here are the last lines of the output:

```
Using ACE for calculation of exact exchange

EXX grid: 915277 G-vectors FFT dimensions: ( 120, 120, 150)
```

What could cause a calculation to fail here?

Comment: Are you sure it's stopped? If it is stopped, what kind of error did you receive? If you didn't receive any error, then I don't think your calculation got stopped. If I recall correctly, when you have memory or disk space shortage, this happens. In the output you see no more line gets printed, but if you observe your CPU usage, you should be able to verify whether the calculation is running or not. If you print the input file and the output file, it would be easier to verify.

Comment: If you used a scheduler like SLURM to submit your job, its output file may provide some insight as well. In addition, note that Hartree–Fock exchange takes MUCH longer than semilocal exchange-correlation, There are double integrals, which take something like (10^6)^2 multiplications on your (large) FFT grid. That will take a good long while!

Comment: Users have started to close this question for being "abandoned". I recommend that you answer any questions that are in the comments, if you want your question to remain open.